# Is there any way to add columns dyamically in jsp/servlet?

Tags: java

I want to know if there is any way to add columns dynamically through user interface.

If the user wants to add extra columns and delete that column, then they can do it by clicking buttons.

Comment: Database columns or html table columns ?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming by column you mean HTML table column. You can use javascript( or jquery) to hide or show column as required or depending upon user preferences.